# Best practices for periodic Django data ingestion and modeling

Tags: django, database-design

I have a CSV file with ~1 million entries I want to model and import into my Django DB. The schema looks something like: `id, name, address, num_employees`.

Every few weeks, the CSV file gets updated - entries get added and deleted, but most stay the same. And rarely the schema changes slightly.

I've read about things like star-schemas, data lakes, ingestion pipelines, data adapters...but there are SO MANY variations and ideas. Some seem overkill, some seem too naive. I'm having trouble understanding where to start. Any best practices or patterns I should follow for this?

Btw, some things I'm interested in:

- Query for the most up to date data.
- Perform some sanity checks and handle things like "keep the old address if it's present in an old entry, but absent in the current version."
- Be able to audit history and manually correct entries that are discovered to be invalid.
- Handle rare schema changes. Maybe next year `address` is split into `street_address, city, state, zip_code`. How can I keep this sane?
- Ingest large files (10-100mb) without holding up my server or bogging down my DB when updating.

Comment: What you have done so far. Have you made the model. What are the fields in your `CSV` file

Comment: The fields are "id, name, address, num_employees"...a few others, but that's the gist of it.

I've done nothing so far, but considered a model with a row per entry - upload and parse the file, deleting anything not there, updating and adding the rest. I've considered keeping all uploaded entries but marking the "active" ones either with a boolean field that I mark false on all old entries or adding a timestamp to each batch and keeping an "active timestamp" setting.

Comment: Your question is sensible but actually a bit too broad - actually there's more than one question here, some of which we may partially answer (at least hint you), some other are lacking context and informations. Also, a lot depends on how you intend to use those data...

Comment: wrt/ schema changes handling, Django has a very powerful schema and data migration tool builtin so it's the obvious solution - but you have to know the schema will change beforehand so you can write and test your migration and deploy it.

Comment: wrt/ "Ingest large files without holding up my server or bogging down my DB", use a custom management command to do the job, eventually add a couple `time.sleep()` calls here and there to avoid hitting too hard on the database, and "chunk" your imports in small/medium size commits (=> commit every X imported rows).

Comment: As more general hints (obvious but anyway): avoid reading the whole file in memory at once (but the csv module will take care of it if you don't do anything stupid), use memoization where it makes sense etc...

Comment: And finally the most obvious advice: start with the simplest desig that could possibly work, test it with real-size data, check how it works and what could be improved - using a profiler if necessary. Despite what some people might think, our mental abilities are rather restricted when it comes to designing a solution for a problem with too many variables and unknown (unless you're  freaking genius possibly but I never met such a specimen so far) so better to start with something simple and improve from there based on effective real feedback.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice and wisdom, bruno! I really appreciate it. I think this gives me some solid ideas and steps forward.

Comment: Hi Soda, can you share at what conclusions you've arrived? I've got a similar challenge.

Comment: Hey @NBajanca - sorry for the slow reply, I only now saw this. I ended up making my own "Ingestor" app with a model to store metadata on each ingestion and the uploaded data (copied to S3). Each ingestion has a schema version and just parses and imports the data manually into the Django DB in batches (each which spins up its own RedisQueue worker). I gave up on having auditable data history, and it's worked fine without. Everything's explicitly defined in the Django model and manually handled, which is simple. Overall, it's pretty ugly, but it works :shrug: